# What is the early 80's sci-fi/horror movie with floating glowing balls, but is NOT Strange Invaders?

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, soft-sci-fi

Does anyone know the early 80's sci-fi or horror movie about floating glowing alien balls? I remember a scene where an adult was lying down (in some sort of bed or pod) suddenly shrivels up, it's a lot like the scene in Strange Invaders where the kid gets the life sucked out of him.

In another scene, I think the closing scene, all these alien glowing balls are shown hovering around above the town at twilight. I think maybe there were people in trees at some point?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Could be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195023/movie-about-flying-spheres-with-saws-which-killed-people/195026#195026 (Phantasm) which has flying balls and shriveling people?

Comment: Thanks moopet, I checked that question before posting, that's not it. This movie had glowing bioligical balls, not chrome robotic ones.